# Отправка зашифрованного пароля на сервер

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте, нужна ваша помощь. Мне нужно при входе пользователя в систему проверять зарегистрирован ли пользователь в системе (в базе данных хранится таблица с учетными записями всех пользователи системы). Но я почитав просторы интернета понял, что желательно хранить не пароль, а хеш от пароля, для нахождения хэша я воспользовался алгоритмом sha-1. Ниже прикреплен php-скрипт сервера принимающего email и пароль, и проверяющего существует ли такая учетная запись или нет. Если существует, то отправляем преобразуем данные в json формат, которые получаем в классе SignUp, если не существует, то ничего.

```
  <?php
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $email = $json->{'Email'};
    $password = $json->{'Password'};
    $values = array();
    $mysqli = new mysqli("*******", *******", "******", ******");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Соединение не установлено: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT UserRegistrations.FullName, UserRegistrations.Email, UserRegistrations.Password, Profiles.IdProfile,
    Profiles.Profile FROM UserRegistrations inner join Profiles on UserRegistrations.ProfileKod = Profiles.IdProfile where 
    Email = '$email' and Password = '$password'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $values[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($values);
}
```

?>

Класс SignUp для отправки запроса к серверу и получение ответа от сервера(в виде json формата), хранящем php-скрипт. В переменной hashSha1 хранится хэш от пароля. При отправке данных, на сервер отправляются email и зашифрованный пароль. Проблема как я думаю заключается в том, данные не доходят до сервера или проблема в php-скрипте. Я пробывал отправить данные на сервер без шифрования все работало, как только зашифровал пароль, и отправил email и пароль на сервер (учетная запись уже существует),но я не получаю учетную запись, хотя она есть в базе данных.

```
 public class SignUp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String emailValue;
    public String passwordValue;
    public String hashSha1;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        emailValue = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        passwordValue = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        MessageDigest sha1 = null;

        try {
            sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            sha1.update(passwordValue.getBytes("ASCII"));
            byte[] data = sha1.digest();
            hashSha1 = convertToHex(data);



        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost("*******");
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json.put("Email", emailValue);
            json.put("Password", hashSha1);

            Log.d(TAG, hashSha1);

            post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);

            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                Log.i("Read from Server", in.toString());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "Sb " + sb.toString());
                if (!sb.toString().equals("")) {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(sb.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        //parse of array
                        JSONObject jObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        fullName = jObject.getString("FullName");
                        email = jObject.getString("Email");
                        password = jObject.getString("Password");
                        profile = jObject.getString("Profile");

                        userregistrations.add(new UserRegistration(fullName, email, password, profile));
                        value = 1;
                        Log.d(TAG, fullName);
                        Log.d(TAG, email);
                        Log.d(TAG, password);
                        Log.d(TAG, profile);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sb == 0");
                    value = 0;

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Перед отправкой данных проверял содержимое hashSha1 там указан правильный пароль(который есть на сервере)

Comment: Решил проблему, нужно было шифровать не на клиенте, а на сервере черезе sha1()

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, нужно было шифровать не на клиенте, а на сервере черезе sha1()